# awk: delete short line from long line

Tags: awk

I have a long file of text strings, sorted by length. What I need to do is find any short lines contained within long lines, breaking up the long line into two shorter lines, and leaving the original short line intact, like this:

```
input:
here is an example of a long line
an example of

output:
here is
a long line
an example of
```

Comment: What if there are multiple possibilities? For example, if the input is `A B C D E`, `B C`, `C D`, which shorter one would you like to remove?

Comment: It will be better if you give real data example and why you like to get out these data.  As Gassa writes, there will be multiple possibility to get different answers.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is build a vim syntax file for arbitrary phrases (of prose). The problem is, there's a lot of partial overlap between the phrases. Not containing/nesting, but partial overlap, which means that the first phrase is highlighted, but the second is not. It's pretty clear there's no way to have overlapped highlighting, so my only option is to get rid of the overlap. I see what you're saying about the multiple possibilities, but because it's only syntax highlighting, it's not a big issue. All the words will still be highlighted either way.

Comment: You know, now that I've written that out, I see I've misstated my need. I need to find the overlap between lines, not nested lines. 

Here are more examples...

`the first`
`first one`

"the first one" will not be properly highlighted -- only "the first."

`the focus was`
`was elsewhere`

In "the focus was elsewhere," only "the focus" will be highlighted.

`the third part`
`part of a`
`a trilogy`
In "the third part of a trilogy," "the third part" and "a trilogy" are highlighted, but not "of." The second phrase is not matched.

At this point, I'm pretty stumped. Should I be looking into ngrams?

Comment: And I should clarify that I'm using a sed script to export the list to a .vim file.

As I continue to think about this, I don't think breaking the phrases up is a meaningful way to highlight the text. I'm going to break this out into new, vim syntax-specific question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted sufficient dataset to allow us to post a complete solution, but here is something to get you started:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR{
  a[$0]++;
  next
}
{
  for(x in a) 
    if(x!=$0 && index($0,x)>0) {
      sub(x FS,"\n")
    }
}1' file file
here is 
a long line
an example of
```

- We are doing two passes to the file. In the first pass, read the lines and store them as key in an array (duplicate lines will get stored as one key).
- In the second pass, we iterate through the array, if the key is not equal to the current line but is a subset of the current line, substitute that smaller word with a newline.